# sending an image over ServerSocket

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am attempting to send an image over `Socket` in Java however I get a `NullPointerException`. Here is the code for server:

```
package sendImage;


import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket client;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server();
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Server(){
        connect();
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void connect(){
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(9999);
            client = server.accept();

            sendImage();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void sendImage(){
        String image = "C:/Users/JavaChild/Downloads/jo-d-101027-mentalist.jpg";
        try{
            InputStream in = Server.class.getResourceAsStream(image);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
            JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Server");
            frame.add(l);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            ImageIO.write(img, "JPG", client.getOutputStream());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

and Client:

```
package sendImage;

import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;


public class Client {
    Socket server;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client();
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Client(){
        connect();
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void connect(){
        try{
            server = new Socket("JavaChild-PC",9999);
            readImage();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void readImage(){
        try{
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(server.getInputStream());
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client");
            frame.add(label);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Please tell me how to send an image properly over the socket**
and **what  is causing the exception?**

### Stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sendImage.Client.readImage(Client.java:37)
    at sendImage.Client.connect(Client.java:28)
    at sendImage.Client.<init>(Client.java:22)
    at sendImage.Client.main(Client.java:18)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @DanW done! The stack trace has been posted! :)

Comment: What line is line 37 exactly?

Comment: @ChrisCooney `JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));` I guess the image is not being sent properly so I am getting a null there

Comment: I would guess that `img` is null in that case. Have you tried debugging to see if you're properly reading in the image?

Comment: Exception in Server at `InputStream in = Server.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(image);
   BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);` it says **input==null**

Comment: Have you tried `InputStream in = new FileInputStream(image);`?

Comment: @Pshemo OK, worked !!!

Comment: @Pshemo You should add that as an answer so poster can accept and people know this is answered.

Comment: @DanW In my opinion beside giving solution answer should also explain problem. I'm not sure why OP code didn't work so decided to post other solution as comment. If you can explain why code from my comment worked but `Server.class.getResourceAsStream` not feel free to post this answer and you will definitely get +1 from me :)